# when after update trigger insert into table but there are old and new value in the inserted table

Tags: mysql

when i make an after update trigger, follow with insert into another table why there are 2 values in another table that i've had inserted?

this is the query 
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `uplb`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `uplb` AFTER UPDATE ON `tb_bayar` FOR EACH ROW
insert into tb_lbayar (id_bayar,id_penghuni,nama,kamar,periode,dateb,jumlah) select old.id_bayar,old.id_penghuni,old.nama,old.kamar,old.periode,old.dateb,new.jumlah

and here's the result in the table that i've inserted :

[image: result]

there are old and new values

and here im just need the new value one

thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure you've only performed 1 update on tb_bayer? Can include a reproducible test case?

Comment: thanks a lot, u're r8. there's a mistake in the model, i performed 2 update at 1 time on tb_bayar @JRD